# How to create enveloped signatures in SOAP with CXF

Tags: soap, jax-ws, cxf, soap-client, ws-security

I have a spec asking for a SOAP body that looks like the example below. Based on my understanding of JAX-RS (see [this page](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-xml-security.html)) this involves creating an "enveloped signature" of the body, but I'm not finding documentation on created enveloped signatures for JAX-WS.

All my attempts to specify individual parts to sign cause additional xml to appear in the header, but I'm unable determine how to sign a part of the body and have the signature appear within the body.  Also please note that the signature is a sub-element of the `bodyComponent` in the example I've been given.

```
<soap:Body xmlns:wsu="http://some.xsd" wsu:Id="id-2">
  <ns2:requestDef xmlns:ns2="http://some-namespace" xmlns="http://another-namespace" xmlns:ns4="http://yet-another-namespace">
    <bodyComponent xmlns = "urn:a:namespace">
      <bodySubComponent>TEST-01</bodySubComponent>
      <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <SignedInfo>
          <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
          <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
          <Reference URI="">
            <Transforms>
              <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethodAlgorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
            <DigestValue>+d1GesY2VzMS8wFAYDVQQD=</DigestValue>
          </Reference>
        </SignedInfo>
        <SignatureValue>+s1GesY2VzMS8wFAYDVQQD= +d1GesY2VzMS8wFAYDVQQD= +d1GesY2VzMS8wFAYDVQQD= +d1GesY2VzMS8wFAYDVQQD= +d1GesY2VzMS8wFAYDVQQD=</SignatureValue>
        <KeyInfo>
          <X509Data>
            <X509SubjectName>CN=A,OU=B,OU=C, OU=D,O=E,C=F</X509SubjectName> 
            <X509Certificate>+x509Y2VzMS8wFAYDVQQD=</X509Certificate>
          </X509Data>
        </KeyInfo>
      </Signature>
    </bodyComponent>
  </ns2:requestDef>
</soap:Body>
```

Using `WSHandlerConstants.SIGNATURE_PARTS` all values are appearing in the `Header`.  Is what I'm trying to do even possible via CXF?

Comment: Still have had no luck with custom interceptors since I essentially want to sign part of the body, then sign and encrypt the entire body again.  It ended up being easier/taking less time to write the entire object to SOAP then sign and sign/encrypt program using wss4j and Java libraries that ship as part of the JDK (core, xml and security).

Comment: could you post an example how u solved it. Im also trying to create an enveloped signatue with cxf, no luck so far

Comment: @AkuNour it's been a long time :), but if I recall I had to do the signing in two passes. See my comment from April 7, 2014.

Comment: Thank for the reply. I solved my issue. Managed to create an enveloped signature without cfx. As i am using apache camel i found a component i could use: http://camel.apache.org/xml-security-component.html